# $f :R\rightarrow R$ continuous function such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq|x-y|$ $ \forall x,y \in R$ Prove that the range of $f$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

$f :\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous function  such that
$|f(x)-f(y)|\geq|x-y|$    $ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$  Prove that the range of $f$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$

What i try
Since f is one - one ($ x\neq y \implies f(x) \neq f(y)$)
Continue one - one function is monotone $\implies $ f  is open map

$f (\mathbb{R}) $ is  open set

If we able to prove  $f (\mathbb{R}) $ is closed   then we are done
Bescuese only subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which both open and closed  are empty or $\mathbb{R}$
Please help in proving $ f(\mathbb{R }) $ is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take sequence $ \{f(x_n) \}$ in  $f(R) $  converging to $ z \in R$  then $ \{f(x_n) \}$ is cauchy
From giving inequality $ \{x_n \}$ is cauchy too (convergent)

Let $(x_n) \rightarrow x$ as $ n\rightarrow \infty$

By continuity  we have

$f(x) = f(\lim x_n) = \lim f(x_n) = z $

So $f(R)$ is closed  ( contain all its limit point)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Observe that

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\ge|x-y|\iff f(x)-f(y)\le-|x-y|\;\text{ and}\;f(x)-f(y)\ge|x-y|$$

Choose $\;y=0\;$ and let $\;x<0\;$, then

$$f(x)-f(0)\le-|x-0|=x\implies f(x)\le x+f(0)\xrightarrow[x\to-\infty]{}-\infty$$

Well, now your turn...

Answer (score 1):

As a warm-up,  note that $f$ must be monotonic.

Given $a\in \Bbb R$, you want to show that there exists $x\in\Bbb R$ with $f(x)=a$. So why not guess $x=0$? Most likely, however, $\delta:=|f(0)-a|$ will be non-zero. So your next best guesses might be $f(\pm\delta)$, which both differ from $f(0)$ by *at least* $\delta$, but in different directions ...